# Stuff function is giving (Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation) error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using STUFF function in a stored procedure like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + ISNULL(sy.YearLevel, 0) 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS YearLevel
```

but I get this error:

> [Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation]

If I do not use `Stuff` and simply use `SELECT sy.yearlevel`, then I have no issue. I am trying to get all year levels on one row that is why I am using the `stuff` function.

Basically this statement is used in a stored procedure to fetch students linked to a debtor (parent). Instead of getting multiple rows for a parent, I wanted to get a single row for each parent.

Comment: Thats only a warning, not an error, and unless the results are actually wrong, it may not be an issue.

Comment: It does not provide me any results. Basically it keeps on repeating that warning for each record

Comment: how about using a cte to iron out null values and then using  stuff in the derived cte?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by Casting yearlevel as Varchar